# Unable to Start RabbitMQ Due to Inconsistent Node

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm attempting to start a RabbitMQ node that was disconnected due an error in setup.

Now I'm unable to start the node because of the inconsistent node error. Reading online, all arrows point to a mnesia directory for node info, but this directory does not exist on my server.

How can I force a node to forget node configuration it the service doesn't start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was the persistence at which my node was retaining the last known connections.

I have to do delete the data in my node's data partition in order for it to forget it's last known connections.

Once deleted I was able to start the node isolated then join it as ram to the disk node.